# How to derive the newtons iterative formula?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Usually in iterative method we find the g(x) and get the iterations.

But here i have a question like
 Derive Newton’s iterative formula to find square root of 23 ?

Here we dont get the possiblities of x right ?
Then how do we solve this problem ?
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take the function $ f(x)=x^2 -23 $

now use the linear interplation or taylor series between 2 sucessive approximations $ x_n , x_{n+1} $

$ f(x_{n+1})=f(x_{n})+f'(x_{n})(x_{n+1}-x_{n}) $  (1)

if we set that for some 'n' then $ f(x_{n+1})=0 $

we can rewritte (1) as  $x_{n+1}=x_{n}- \frac{f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n}} $

whic is the iterative newton method